# UIView Hide Completly

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitabbar

I've implemented A Custom UITabbar ( made from scratch ) but the problem that when I try to use KTPhotoBrowser when I browse the photos it is still shown and when I set it Hidden or removeFromSuperView I white bar in its place , how can I remove the view completely ?
EDIT : Ended up hiding the view of the tabbar

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 0):

It may depends on hw is structured your UIView hierarchy. Post the code or try to set hidden the superview of the UITabbar or the tab bar itself.

Comment: the code is that is here http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/

Comment: when I set the superview the view become black